# Creating dropdown from database in codeigniter with helper functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I am trying to populate a dropdown from database in codeigniter. To do this, I have extended the form_helper class in MY_form_helper and created  the following function.

```
function Create_Dropdown($table, $columns, $type = '', $class = '') {
    $CI =& get_instance();
$query = $CI->db->get($table);

if ($query->num_rows >= 1) {
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $data[$row[$columns[0]]] = $row[$columns[1]];
    }
    return $data;
}
}
```

I want to know if it the correct way to achieve this by getting the instance using get_instance and using it here. I want this function to be available in all my controllers.

Comment: in this helper you are just returngin $data to the calling variable so need to see you view to help your properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Create_Dropdown($table, $columns, $type = '', $class = '') {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $query = $CI->db->select($columns)->get($table); // instead of select (*)

    if ($query->num_rows >= 1) {
       return array_column($query->result_array(), $columns[1], $columns[0]);
    }
}
```